# Storing primitives in XML

Tags: json, node.js, xml, primitive-types

I haven't used XML in ages, mostly just using JSON for serialized data.
I am working on creating a homegrown XML to JSON converter for usage with Node.js, not that easy but should be doable.

What is the standard for storing primitive types, all I can think of is:

```
<root>
  <a type="string">foobar</a>
  <b type="boolean">true</b>
  <c type="number">69</c>
</root>
```

is there no better way than that?

Comment: We have XSD which can control which data types are allowed in which elements. I don't see why types need to be stored in the XML itself. Seems error-prone (boolena vs boolean vs Boolean etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While XML Schema is normally used for declaring the content and lexical types of your document in a schema, it has also established the `xsi:type` attribute as an idiom to express a dynamically-typed element or attribute, as well as the XML Schema data types for strings, numbers, dates, etc.

Using XML Schema data types and `xsi:type` for your example looks as follows:

```
<root
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <a xsi:type="xsd:string">foobar</a>
  <b xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</b>
  <c xsi:type="xsd:unsignedInt">69</c>
</root>
```